# expressjs automatically end with json?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I'm using expressjs to serve json.

If I try to res.end() with an object I get:

```
TypeError: first argument must be a string, Array, or Buffer
```

Is there a setting or a middleware that would automatically stringify before end or somehow make this work without putting json.stringify everywhere?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using express there is a send method witch stringify's it

Comment: on the response object that is

Comment: wait, so if I want json then I just use send? Then what's the point of end... I feel like i wasted a lot of time lol

Comment: ... end is the original API method from Node's http response object.

Comment: Node's res.end provides bare-bones (String only) capabilities as per the node philosophy.  Express's res.send handles several different types automatically and does the right thing as per Express's philosophy.